# How to create an Object in my sbt build so I can use in my application?

Tags: scala, sbt

How can I create a variable during my build phase so I can reference it in my application.

For example, create a class like:

```
Object BuildMeta {
  val buildTime = //... this value is set when I run sbt compile
}
```

There are other things I want to do, but that is the basic idea.

How can I then reference this BuildMeta class from within my Play application?

Comment: You can't. At least not directly. Your build is not your application. What do you want to do?

Comment: You need a custom sbt task and the sbt-buildinfo Plugin.https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a var in runtime you can use:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime
```

But when you are executing SBT you are not in runtime.

Other thing is that if you want to take a date or something like thatm while you are executing sbt package, then you can run it from an script, take the date (or the value you want) and then read if from a file while in runtime in your Scala code. This is perfectly possible